# Error launching RemoteWebDriver test from Eclipse

Tags: java, json, firefox, selenium, remotewebdriver

I get the following message in the Eclipse console:

unable to create selected WebDriver; exiting early.
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : {platform=ANY, browserName=firefox, version=}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: check the nodeConfig.json file and confirm that the intended browser is included in the capabilities object.  In this problem, the "firefox" name:value pairs were missing.

```
"capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },      
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "browserName": "internet explorer",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ],
```